# PHP execution takes longer than it should, why?

Tags: php

I have a large database with 1800 contact records. A php script is being used to facilitate "Word Mailmerge". When I do a mailmerge with 500 records, it takes around 40 seconds. But to do same for 1800 records, execution time for the task is around 300 seconds, where it should take no more than 180-200 seconds.

I have tweaked around PHP.ini and php-fpm config and increase some values, but no improvement in results. Is it normal for PHP when executing large no of records?

Comment: my php settings? or original code of php scripts?

Comment: The PHP script that facilitates "Word Mailmerge"

Comment: its not a single script, but its here https://github.com/veda-consulting/uk.co.vedaconsulting.module.wordmailmerge

Comment: `1800 contact records` or `1-800-contacts records`?    ;)

Comment: its 1800 contact records

Comment: So - you're asking us to troubleshoot a library you are using from GitHub? Why not ask the **author of the library** rather than this community?  You need someone familiar with that library, so you should at least include that detail in the question.

Comment: well, i guess you did not read my question correctly, so, again "I have tweaked around PHP.ini and php-fpm config and increase some values, but no improvement in results. Is it normal for PHP when executing large no of records?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it exactly 300 seconds (i.e 5 minutes) every time?  If so, I think you might be getting stuck on one of the records somehow and PHP is hitting its max_execution_time.

Try running your script with the latter 1300 of the 1800 (by adding `LIMIT 501, 1300` to your query).  Does it take 300s?

Try splitting the recordset in half (by adding `LIMIT 0, 900` in one attempt then `LIMIT 901,900` in the next).  Take the set that results in the 300s execution time and split *that* in half -- continue until you find the record that is causing your trouble.

Investigate that record and see why it's causing an infinite loop or hang.

Also, do you have `E_ALL` error reporting on?  You may have Notices or Warnings that may shed some light on the issue.

**UPDATE:**

In your script, where you have your query string defined, add an `echo` with a concatenated `<br>` after the assignment and before the query call itself.  Then wrap that `echo` in `ob_end_flush();` and `ob_start();`.

For example, if, you had code like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {contacts};";
$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

change it to:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM {contacts};";

ob_end_flush();
# CODE THAT NEEDS IMMEDIATE FLUSHING
echo $query . "<br>";
ob_start();

$result = mysqli_query($query);
```

This will make PHP echo the query string immediately without waiting for the script execution to end or for the buffer to fill.  Then you can see the output while the script is still running and determine immediately what's actually happening (either the script is getting hung on a single, specific record OR the execution time is legitimately increasing as your iterate over an increasing amount of records).

If you actually share your code, I'd be able to help a lot more.

Comment: thanks, its helpful. I will try...

Comment: @Tapash, any luck?  if so, please accept this answer as the solution.

Comment: yes, I have tried, it seems my webserver & php settings are working perfectly. But as I increase the no of contacts after 200 records processing time increases. I will contact the developer. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @Tapash.  Try increasing the number of records very slowly until the processing time increases.  Once you find the record that the script is hanging on, take a look at it in the database -- I'd bet you'll find something wrong with it.  Did you have E_ALL error reporting on?

Comment: @Tapash, See my UPDATE in my Answer, please.

Answer (score 1):

1800 is a very small number of records and shouldn't take any amount of time at all to process.  Can you provide a little more detail on the process itself?  Is it a webpage / background process?  Are you sending the same data to all of these users?

This type of thing should be handled by a worker / background process so, typically, you shouldn't care how long it takes (within reason) providing the job completes.  That said, because it is such a small range, you could troubleshoot the process by trying to send 250 first and set the base time for what you expect as an average of 250 records to be sent.  Increase by 250 each time.  If the average time increases each time you increment the batch size then you can pretty be sure you have an issue with the code - in which case post it here and we can try to resolve for you.  If the average increases only within a specific window (e.g. between 750 and 1000) then it is likely a data issue.

This is as simple an approach as I can suggest without seeing any code or having any extra detail.